# Delphi android - Send data from local foreground service to application

Tags: android, delphi, foreground-service

I have an application launching a foreground local service. I'm able to send commands from application to the service. I also need to send data (Ex : location) from the foreground local service to the application. Embarcadero provides an example using notification center but it does not work at all  : http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Sydney/en/FMX.Android_Notification_Service_Sample. I compiled the sample and installed it on my device, nothing is received, of course same behaviour with my application : I get the notification in device, not in the application.

I read a lot of posts about communication between service and application, most of them in java, but I have no clue of how to implement it with delphi. I guess the simplest way is to use intent as I have no much data to send. Something like this ? :

In service something like this :

```
IntentMes := TJIntent.Create;
IntentMes.addCategory(TJIntent.JavaClass.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
IntentMes.setAction(StringToJString(svcIntentAction)); // svcIntentAction = fr.MyApp.SVC
IntentMes.putExtra(StringToJString(svcIntentData),StringToJString('Hello'));
TAndroidHelper.Context.sendBroadcast(Intent); // Very not sure of that
```

In application something like that :

```
function MyApp.HandleIntentAction(const Data: JIntent): Boolean;
var svcData : string;
begin
  Result := False;
  if Data <> nil then begin
    if Data.hasExtra(StringToJString(svcIntentData)) then begin
      svcData := JStringToString(Data.getStringExtra(StringToJString(svcIntentData)));
      result := true;

      // process data...
    end;

  end;
end;
```

In manifest file :

```
<intent-filter>  
    <action android:name="fr.MyApp.SVC" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

I also need to be sure that application is running before sending data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one *possible* way of doing what you want, based on some code based on what I use in this demo:

https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/Kastri/tree/master/Demos/CrossPlatformLocation

What follows is the basics of that work, but the premise is the same, i.e. create an instance of a class that implements JFMXBroadcastReceiverListener, which adds the appropriate action, and assign a handler to the OnMessageReceived event. "Data" are sent via the SendMessage method.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  Androidapi.JNIBridge, Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes, Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText, Androidapi.JNI.Embarcadero;

type
  // Import that is missing from Delphi - it would pay to split this off into a separate unit
  JLocalBroadcastManager = interface;

  JLocalBroadcastManagerClass = interface(JObjectClass)
    ['{5CCF81B2-E170-47C4-873E-32E644085880}']
    {class} function getInstance(context: JContext): JLocalBroadcastManager; cdecl;
  end;

  [JavaSignature('android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager')]
  JLocalBroadcastManager = interface(JObject)
    ['{B5D9B2DA-E150-4CC5-BBDA-58FCD42C6C1E}']
    procedure registerReceiver(receiver: JBroadcastReceiver; filter: JIntentFilter); cdecl;
    function sendBroadcast(intent: JIntent): Boolean; cdecl;
    procedure sendBroadcastSync(intent: JIntent); cdecl;
    procedure unregisterReceiver(receiver: JBroadcastReceiver); cdecl;
  end;
  TJLocalBroadcastManager = class(TJavaGenericImport<JLocalBroadcastManagerClass, JLocalBroadcastManager>) end;

  TMessageReceivedEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; const Msg: string) of object;

  // Local broadcast receiver class
  TLocalReceiver = class(TJavaLocal, JFMXBroadcastReceiverListener)
  private
    FAction: JString;
    FBroadcastReceiver: JFMXBroadcastReceiver;
    FIntentFilter: JIntentFilter;
    FOnMessageReceived: TMessageReceivedEvent;
    procedure DoMessageReceived(const AMsg: string);
  public
    { JFMXBroadcastReceiverListener }
    procedure onReceive(context: JContext; intent: JIntent); cdecl;
  public
    constructor Create(const AAction: string);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property OnMessageReceived: TMessageReceivedEvent read FOnMessageReceived write FOnMessageReceived;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    FReceiver: TLocalReceiver;
    procedure ReceiverMessageReceivedHandler(Sender: TObject; const AMsg: string);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

uses
  Androidapi.Helpers;

const
  cLocalBroadcastExtraMessage = 'MESSAGE';

// e.g. SendMessage('SERVICE_MESSAGE', 'Hello world');
procedure SendMessage(const AAction, AMessage: string);
var
  LIntent: JIntent;
begin
  LIntent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init(StringToJString(AAction));
  LIntent.putExtra(StringToJString(cLocalBroadcastExtraMessage), StringToJString(AMessage));
  TJLocalBroadcastManager.JavaClass.getInstance(TAndroidHelper.Context).sendBroadcast(LIntent);
end;

{ TLocalReceiver }

constructor TLocalReceiver.Create(const AAction: string);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FAction := StringToJString(AAction);
  FBroadcastReceiver := TJFMXBroadcastReceiver.JavaClass.init(Self);
  FIntentFilter := TJIntentFilter.JavaClass.init;
  FIntentFilter.addAction(FAction);
  TJLocalBroadcastManager.JavaClass.getInstance(TAndroidHelper.Context).registerReceiver(FBroadcastReceiver, FIntentFilter);
end;

destructor TLocalReceiver.Destroy;
begin
  TJLocalBroadcastManager.JavaClass.getInstance(TAndroidHelper.Context).unregisterReceiver(FBroadcastReceiver);
  FBroadcastReceiver := nil;
end;

procedure TLocalReceiver.onReceive(context: JContext; intent: JIntent);
begin
  if intent.getAction.equals(FAction) then
    DoMessageReceived(JStringToString(intent.getStringExtra(StringToJString(cLocalBroadcastExtraMessage))));
end;

procedure TLocalReceiver.DoMessageReceived(const AMsg: string);
begin
  if Assigned(FOnMessageReceived) then
    FOnMessageReceived(Self, AMsg);
end;

{ TForm1 }

constructor TForm1.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  // For the service, do a similar setup with an instance of TLocalReceiver, but use an action of something like 'APP_MESSAGE'
  FReceiver := TLocalReceiver.Create('SERVICE_MESSAGE'); // i.e. receiving messages from the service
  FReceiver.OnMessageReceived := ReceiverMessageReceivedHandler;
end;

destructor TForm1.Destroy;
begin
  FReceiver.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TForm1.ReceiverMessageReceivedHandler(Sender: TObject; const AMsg: string);
begin
  // Handle AMsg here
end;

end.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, that's exactly what I need.